# How to create a Scrollable Table in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so this is basically about scrollable tables.

If I have a table element I can make the content scrollable (with some javascript fun, including accouting for the scroll bar using the width) by making the thead fixed height, and the tbody fixed height, then setting scrolling to auto on the tbody.

This works in Firefox, but in google chrome the heights on the thead/tbody are ignored and the whole table grows vs scrolling as intended.

Is there a css solution that can be applied to the table to make this work in google chrome as well? Or do I need to make the header one table, the body a different table, ensure the column widths using js or css and have the parent of the body table scroll with it's content?

Comment: That would be horribly non-semantic markup. Have you tried setting the height for the whole table?

Comment: Height on the table acts as a min-height property. Can't force the table to be only a certain hight. I wanted a solution that would not require me to split the table into two tables one for head one for foot with set column widths.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution that should work ( using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) 
You will need to have two tables each one in a separate div element. Each table will have the same thead section. Only contentTable will have the tbody section

```
<div class="scrollableTable"
    <div>
        <table class="headerTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
     <div style="height:240px; overflow:auto;">
        <table class="contentTable" style="width:100%; margin-top:-20px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>value 1</td>
                    <td>value 2</td>
                    <td>value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>value 4</td>
                    <td>value 5</td>
                    <td>value 6</td>
                </tr>
                ....
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, you will have to call this function each time the data is changed :

```
ResizeWidths($('.scrollableTable'));


function ResizeWidths(div)
{
    var headerCells =  $(div).find('.headerTable thead').find('th');
    var contentCells = $(div).find('.contentTable thead').find('th');
    for(var i =0, ii = headerCells.length;i<ii;i++)
    {
        if($(headerCells[i]).width()!=$(contentCells[i]).width())
            $(headerCells[i]).width($(contentCells[i]).width());
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted a solution in a single table, which works on all browsers other than chrome, I am just trying to understand why chrome is not working out.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid something like this, but it really looks like I might have no choice but to do it this way.

Comment: I've tested it on IE7/8,Chrome and FF and it works well. I've added 2 things: 1) `$(div).find('.contentTable')[0].style['marginTop'] = 
'-' + $(contentCells[0]).height() + 'px';` to assign dynamically the negative margin-top. 2) code to synchronize horizontal scrolling between header and content divs. In FF and Chrome I've used onscroll event. In IE 7/8 I've added a 100ms setInterval calling the sync method (I know, ugly, but works).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were using the script from the following [page](http://www.webtoolkit.info/demo/scrollable-html-table)

In order to fix the bug occuring in the Chrome change the following lines:

```
 if (document.all && document.getElementById && !window.opera) this.initIEengine();
    if (!document.all && document.getElementById && !window.opera) this.initFFengine();
```

to this:

```
 var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    if (is_chrome = true) {
        this.initIEengine()
    }
    else {
        if (document.all && document.getElementById && !window.opera) this.initIEengine();
        if (!document.all && document.getElementById && !window.opera) this.initFFengine();
    }
```

Works perfectly then

Comment: Not using that script... But is this a global thing that will set some IE behaviors in the whole page? That feels closer to using a nuke to kill a mouse. Still very good to know there is something that can be done.